# Android BroadcastReceiver for internet connection called twice

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-networking

I am facing this issue for a while and noticed that a few other people also faced it, but I am not able to resolve it.

**The Problem**

I have a BroadcastReceiver, which keeps listening for the internet changes. So whenever the internet is connected or disconnected, I get the status in `onReceive` of the receiver.

The problem is it is always getting called twice. When I connect the debugger and have the breakpoint in the code, I can see it getting called twice but my code on status change executes. When the debugger is not connected, in that case my code on status change doesn't execute at all.

**My Code**

**BroadcastReceiver file**

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver
    extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

public ConnectivityReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
        connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
    }
}

public static boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager
            cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}


public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
}

}
```

**Manifest intent action**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".utils.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

here when I tried with only `<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />` in filter, then also it came to `onRecieve` twice. And when I tried with `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />`, then I didn't come to `onReceive` at all.

**BaseActivity**

```
 @Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    setNetworkIndicator(isConnected); //THE CODE TO EXECUTE ON STATUS CHANGE
}
```

I tried the existing answers, and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

For **Android 7** and above you need to register your receiver in your activity file not in the manifest file.

So in your activity's **onCreate()** add the following lines:

```
    myConnectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(getResources().getString(R.string.action_connectivity_change));
    registerReceiver(myConnectivityReceiver,filter);
```

and in **onDestroy()**

```
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      unregisterReceiver(myConnectivityReceiver);
      super.onDestroy();
  }
```

define the intent action in strings.xml

```
<string name="action_connectivity_change">android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE</string>
```

Comment: Epic answer! Defining  and passing R.string.action_connectivity_change to addAction() did the trick for me. I wasn't able to import the constant otherwise. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My guess here is that the wifi receiver gets called twice because it gets called once for the **enabling** state, and once for the followup **enabled** state.

In the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) it is stated that:

> Broadcast intent action indicating that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled, enabling, disabling, or unknown. One extra provides this state as an int. Another extra provides the previous state, if available.

You can check the values of [EXTRA_WIFI_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#EXTRA_WIFI_STATE) and [EXTRA_PREVIOUS_WIFI_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#EXTRA_PREVIOUS_WIFI_STATE) to verify if this is the case.

So in order to ignore the unwanted *connecting/disconnecting* states, you could update your *onReceive()* to the following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (activeNetwork != null){

        if (activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING || activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING){
            return;
        }
        isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }

    if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
        connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here for the network state the code is `activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()` this is what I posted the question.
But I tried a couple of times with `activeNetwork.isConnected()` also, and it didn't work out

Comment: Nope, it is false in both the cases when I disconnect, and When I connect, it's false first and true second time

Comment: So this is excactly the case i described. When you connect and the onReceive() is called the first time, isConnected() is false because the device is still in the connecting state. When its called the second time, the device was connected successfully, so isConnected() is true.

Comment: Understood.. So any possible solution in your mind that might work?

Comment: Still it is getting called twice. First time it is always null. Second time the value is there

Answer (score 0):

Usually,when on Receive is called twice broadcast receiver called twice.So please check you are registering the broadcast in 2 locations? If yes then Please **register your broadcast only** in resume or create and also **unregistered it onPause()** method of activity.

**For Example Register Broadcast receiver,**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myLocalBroadcastManager, new IntentFilter(Constant.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE));
```

**Unregistered Broadcast Receiver like:-**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myLocalBroadcastManager);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried.
Earlier, I was registering it in Manifest, as stated in question. Now I tried registering it from java in `onResume` and deregistered in `onPause`, but it didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check the intent action in the onReceive callback:

```
String action = arg1.getAction();
if (action != null && action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    // do your task here.
}
```